# Почему в ответ приходит Undefined variable

Tags: php, http, rest, postman

Учусь делать REST API на PHP. Дело в том, что у меня сам АПИ разбит на неск. файлов, поэтому я подключаю их с помощью `require_once 'api/account.php`. Далее я инициализирую переменную:

```
# APIs
require_once 'api/account.php';
$account = new Account();
```

В самом классе есть публичная функция signup, которую мне нужно использовать после приёма POST с ссылкой /signup. Выходит такая штука:

```
switch($uri) { // uri - переменная, в которой $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] без '/'
  case 'signup':
    $query = $account->signup($_POST['fname'], $_POST['sname']);
    if($query) ret(200, 'OK', json_encode($account->returnData()));
    else ret(404, 'Not found', json_encode($account->returnError()));
    break;
}
```

Функция `signup` возвращает true или false, в зависимости от результата, `returnData` и `returnError` возвращают массивы.

Для теста использую PostMan. При запросе выдаёт:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: account in C:\laragon\www\test_module\index.php on line 38
```

Каким образом можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: что же конкретно находится на стр. 38??

Comment: __Где__ устанавливается значение `$account`?

Comment: `function signup (Account $account) { ... }` используем в коде `signup($account);`. Неужели так сложно?!